Are the locations on the timezones static in the GMT offset?
I have a question regarding how the Timezones are maintained in Salesforce and if they are static/constants.
In Salesforce, I can see that for 'America/Chicago' that it is in the timezone of Central Daylight Time, which is GMT-5. My question is: Will it always be Central Daylight Time? Or once Daylight Savings ends, will it change to Central Standard Time, which is GMT-6?
I need to know if the timezone is fixed as I want to use the location of the Timezone field to calculate the GMT offset.
Thanks.

The TimeZone class that you use for calculating time offsets do calculate the correct offset based on the Time Zone and the GMT time.
DateTime winterBegins = DateTime.newInstance(2023, 12, 21, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime summerBegins = DateTime.newInstance(2023, 6, 21, 0, 0, 0);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('America/Chicago');
System.debug(tz.getOffset(winterBegins)); //-21600000
System.debug(tz.getOffset(summerBegins)); //-18000000

Note that the output values are in milliseconds offset from GMT, so you'll typically want to divide by 60000 to get the number of minutes offset. Time zones that don't observe DST won't see any offset changes.
Also, the DST tables will reflect any variations that may occur over time. For example, should the Sunshine Protection Act be passed in America, DST will no longer apply for future times after the bill is signed into law and takes effect, but will still return the correct offset for past dates (i.e. the code above will always return the same values).
